# Conditional filters in Shiny: Can't convert <character> to <list>

Tags: r, filter, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps

To understand Shiny I am trying to create an app that could let the user select several of the categories of var_1 (see **input** below) in one select menu and then show only the available options within those categories in a second select menu. The **output** should show var_1 selection in the first column, var_2 on the second column, and var_3 should be shown as columns (I have used pivot_wider for this) and if the element in var_3 is present on the selection or not ("yes" or "no").
Maybe by looking at my input and output tables, I am able to explain my objective in a better way:

**input**(tf in the code below)

| var_1 | var_2 | var_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| red | table1 | column1 |
| red | table1 | column1 |
| red | table1 | column1 |
| blue | table2 | column2 |
| blue | table2 | column2 |
| blue | table2 | column2 |
| green | table3 | column3 |
| green | table3 | column3 |
| green | table3 | column3 |

**output**

| var_1 | var_2 | column1 | column2 | column3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| red | table1 | Yes | No | No |
| red | table1 | Yes | No | No |
| red | table1 | Yes | No | No |
| blue | table2 | No | Yes | No |
| blue | table2 | No | Yes | No |
| blue | table2 | No | Yes | No |
| green | table3 | No | No | Yes |
| green | table3 | No | No | Yes |
| green | table3 | No | No | Yes |

Here is the code I have used to try to build the app but I keep getting errors I will show below the code:

```
library(shinyWidgets)

tf<-test_2_filtros

shinyApp(
  ui = pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Conditional Filters"),
    sidebarPanel(
      selectizeGroupUI(
        id = "my-filters",
        inline = FALSE,
        params = list(
          var_one = list(inputId = "var_1", title = "Select variable 1", placeholder = 'select'),
          var_two = list(inputId = "var_2", title = "Select variable 2", placeholder = 'select')
        )
      )
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("table")
    )
  ),
  
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    
    res_mod <- callModule(
      module = selectizeGroupServer,
      id = "my-filters",
      data = tf,
      vars = c("var_1", "var_2")
    )
    
  
    
    output$table <- renderTable({
      res_mod()%>% 
        dplyr::mutate(n = "Yes")%>%
        tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = var_3, values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = "No"))
    })
    
  },
  
  options = list(height = 500)
)
```

These are the errors and warnings I am getting right now:

> Warning: Values are not uniquely
> identified; output will contain list-cols.
>
> - Use `values_fn = list` to suppress this warning.
> - Use `values_fn = length` to identify where the duplicates arise
> - Use `values_fn = {summary_fun}` to summarise duplicates

> Warning: Error in: Can't convert character to list.

Thanks for any suggestions you could give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is caused by duplicate rows in your data.  You can fix it by defining a unique id, with a `row_num` as shown below.

```
 output$table <- renderTable({
      req(res_mod())
      res_mod() %>% 
        dplyr::mutate(n = "Yes") %>%
        mutate(row_num = 1:n()) %>%
        tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = var_3, values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = "No")) %>% 
        select(-row_num)
    })
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. I wonder how could I avoid showing the row number in the output table. Is that possible?

Comment: @AFS, please try the updated code.  You can use `select(-row_num)` to remove the column.

Comment: Hello @YBS your solution was running perfectly with the mock data I posted (a set of 9 observations and 3 variables). Now that I am testing it with the real data (487 observations and 3 variables) y get this: "Error: Problem with `mutate()` column`row_num`.
[34mℹ[39m `row_num = 1:n()`.
[34mℹ[39m `row_num` must be size 0 or 1, not 2."                                           
What might be wrong with row_num? I am not even sure if this is related to the new dataset. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Also, please use `dplyr::mutate`.  If that does not work, please post a sample of data that has some unique nuances as in real data.

Comment: It works! Thanks